# Hover to change divs content

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would i create a hover function that displays an image over the entire display-div?
Lets say that I would hover over `item1`, then an image would cover display-div, if i hover over another `item`, the image within the display-div should change to that.  https://jsfiddle.net/urvmgk8e/1/ (not working)

```
Nav-div          Display-div
--------------  -------------
|            | |            |
| >>item1<<  | |content for |   
|   item2    | |   item1    |   
|   item3    | |            |       
|            | |            |
|            | |            |
|            | |            |
--------------  --------------
```

Jquery:

```
$("a.menu").click(function(e) {
  $('.ShowClickedContent').html($($(this).attr('href')).html()); //Display-div container
});
```

The problem is that, my jquery function only reacts to click-events. How would i make it so that it would react on mouseOver?
[image]

Comment: Change event from `click` to `mouseover`?

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately as i'm using the function above also to show content once the user has clicked on the item. Somehow, they are interfering.

Comment: Provide a minimal and working example then.

Comment: updated. check my jsfiddle, but my jquery doesnt seem to work in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's hover function or mouseover. I wrote an example by my understanding: http://codepen.io/Kalan/pen/wJpYoL

```js
$("#first").hover(function(){
  $("#display img").css("display","block");
  
},function(){
  $("#display img").css("display","");
  none
  
});
```

```css
#display img
{
  display: none;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
  <span id="first">Hover</span>
</div>
<div id="display">
  <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" />
</div>
```

The .hover function has as parameters two handlers, the first handler is a callback function, which is invoked when you hover over the item and it executes the code, the second is handler out function, which is executed when you unhover the item.

Answer (score 1):

Refactored your code a little bit, seems to work fine. Tell me if it's exactly what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".menu2").hover(function() {
    $('.showClickedContent').html($($(this).attr('href')).html())
  }, function() {
    $('.showClickedContent').html('')
  });

  $(".parent").find('h2').click(function() {
    $(".c").fadeOut();
    $(".c").eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();

  });

});
```

```css
a {
  margin: 0 0.3em;
  font-family: "arial";
  text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent' style="background-color:#fff;margin-top:0;padding:0;">

  <h2><a href="#test1" title="test1" class="menu2">test1</a></h2>
  <h2><a href="#test2" title="test1" class="menu2">test2</a></h2>
  <h2><a href="#test3" title="test1" class="menu2">test3</a></h2>

</div>

<div class="showClickedContent" style="background-color:#fff;"></div>

<div id="test1" class='c' style="display:none;background-color:#fff;">
  <h2>test1</h2>
</div>
<div id="test2" class='c' style="display:none;background-color:#fff;">
  <h2>test2</h2>
</div>
<div id="test3" class='c' style="display:none;background-color:#fff;">
  <h2>test3</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, almost, the problem is that, if a user actually `clicks` the link, content should be displayed (regardless if they hover over another link and then hover out). step-by-step what i want to accomplish: 1. user clicks link => div is displayed. 2. user hovers a link => an image is displayed in that same  `display-div`

Comment: @Joel Check now?

Comment: I rephrased my comment :)

Comment: please navigate to http://d289077c.ngrok.io/wordpress/clients/ and check the clients page. I will store your code on there for right now. What I would like is for there to be an image that covers the "display-div" entirely when a user hovers a link. But if they click an option, the content should be displayed. As of now, it goes away when a user hovers over another link.

Comment: I had to remove it now, but hopefully you get my point with what i'm trying to accomplish now.

Comment: @Joel I've checked it and I'm still not sure about it. If you could explain slowly and accurately step by step...

Comment: ok. User lands on page. An image is shown over the "content-div". IF a user clicks a link, they should be shown the content for that link. (as it is now). But, if the user decides to hover of a link, they will be presented with a related image to that company in the same "content-div".
So, pretty much, if a user hovers over an image, a related image should be shown, if they click on that very same link they are hovering, the content should change to whatever content there is now.

Comment: i know, but its the principle. I want to show another div if the user is hovering, and if they click, the div that is showing now, is going to be shown.

Comment: @Joel Check it out.

Comment: almost! check the link again, it comes out in a new container instead of the same as the content. hmm.. thanks for your contribution, means a lot!

Comment: @Joel Tell me what's else to do with it ;d

Comment: ehm, look at what happens if you click a link, it pops out below the menu now instead of being displayed within the display-nav.

Comment: @Joel I've positioned it because it didn't look nice... ;p

Comment: @Joel I'm on my companys laptop and some firewall doesn't let me through this link :(

Comment: hmm, i'll upload screenshot to question. as you can see, instead of being placed within the container, it is being placed below the menu

Comment: @Joel It's hard to deduce anything only after seeing the picture :(

Comment: sorry took a new picture now. The container to the right, is where i want both the hovered content, and the clicked content to appear.
within that same container so to speak, if a user hovers, it is replaced with the hovered div, if the user has clicked a link before, that should be what is displayed. I dont know how to explain it more in another way xD
The container to the right. That is where everything should happen. IF a user clicks, content should be displayed, if a user hovers a link, that content should be replaced with another div. then if user "un-hovers,  return to clicked content.

Comment: @Joel Bro, it's all about positioning. Just drag and drop the whole code under the `parent` div into any div you want. So it will appear in the div you want.

Comment: No man, i want both of them to be shown within the same container. not two different ones. i have everything under the .parent container, it still creates two different ones.